# Ionic tap pushnotification not redirecting ios10

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ios10

Made an app using ionic and published on app store. When ever app receives notification and user taps on it , User profile settings view is opened.  It is working fine on ios 9 but on ios 10 after clicking on notification . App showing home view(1st screen) not redirecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to do two thing to get push notification work again in iOS 10.
1) Enable push notification in xCode 8 GM capabilities in targets.
2) Update your existing ionic plugin to support push notification for iOS 10 and re submit app to app store.

Adding push notifications capability does 2 things
1)add the push notification feature to your app id
2)add push notification entitlement to your entitlements file